# how to add an icon-link in kendo ui treeview

Tags: kendo-ui, treeview, kendo-treeview

Here is my KendoUI tree view, I want to add 'edit' icon to all the nodes and then give a url to it, twhich takes the id of the node, and goes to edit page,

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var  homogeneous = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
        transport: {
            read: {
                type:'POST',
                url: rootURL + "Territory/AllTerritories",
                dataType: "json"
            }
        },
        schema: {
            model: {
                id: "ID",
                hasChildren: "HasChildren",
                children: homogeneous

            }
        }
    });

    $("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
        dataSource: homogeneous,
        dataTextField: "Name",
        dataValueField: "ID",


    });

</script>
```

I can see the TreeView being generated, Please help!

Answer (score 1):

in your code little changes like this

```html
<script type="text/javascript">

  var  homogeneous = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
        transport: {
            read: {
                type:'POST',
                url: rootURL + "Territory/AllTerritories",
                dataType: "json"
            }
        },
        schema: {
            model: {
                id: "ID",
                hasChildren: "HasChildren",
                children: homogeneous,
                image :"url"

            }
        }
    });

    $("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
        dataSource: homogeneous,
        dataTextField: "Name",
        dataValueField: "ID",
        dataImageUrlField: "image"


    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Kendo UI Template for that:

```
<script id="treeview-template" type="text/kendo-ui-template">
      <a class='show-link' href='\#'><image src="/imageUrl"></a>
</script>


$("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
    dataSource: homogeneous,
    dataTextField: "Name",
    dataValueField: "ID",

    template: kendo.template($("#treeview-template").html()
});
```

http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/treeview/templates

Comment: I did as told above, 
  but now I am getting the error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined